# The jth factorial moment of X ~ Geo(p)

Tags: probability

Define $E[{X \choose j}]=E[X(X-1)(X-2) \dots (X-j+1)]/j\,!$ which $G_X(s)$ is a probability generating function.
$E[X(X-1)(X-2) \dots (X-j+1)]=G_X^{(j)}(s=1)$
$E[{X \choose j}]$ is called the jth binomial moment of $X$.
I have obtained $P(X=x)=\sum_{j=x}^{\infty}(-1)^{j-x}{j \choose x}E[{X \choose j}]$.
If $X \sim Geo(p)$, then $P(X=x)=p(1-p)^x$.
How to prove $E[{X \choose j}]=(\frac{1-p}{p})^j$ if $X \sim Geo(p)$?
We can substitute $P(X=x)$ and get the equation $p(1-p)^x=\sum_{j=x}^{\infty}(-1)^{j-x}{j \choose x}E[{X \choose j}]$.
How to simplify the equation above?

Comment: I think $E[{x \choose j}]$ have different definitions in these two question.

Comment: That's right. But you can apply the method of the linked answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your question, you just need to take your equation
$$
E\left[\binom{X}j\right]=G^{(j)}_X(1)/j!,
$$
and substitute in the probability generating function for the geometric distribution, which is
$$
G_X(s)=E[s^X]=\sum_{k=0}^\infty s^k \cdot p (1-p)^k=\frac{p}{1-s(1-p)}.
$$
Now you just differentiate $j$ times and set $s=1$. One way to do this is to compute $G^{(1)}(s),G^{(2)}(s),G^{(3)}(s),\dots$ by hand until you notice a pattern, then prove the pattern holds by induction. Alternatively, you find all of the derivatives of $G_X(s)$ at $s=1$ by expanding as a Taylor series centered at $1$:
$$
\frac{p}{1-s(1-p)}=\frac{1}{1-\frac{1-p}{p}(s-1)}=\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1-p}{p}\right)^j(s-1)^j,\tag{$|\tfrac{1-p}p(s-1)|<1$}
$$
which implies $G^{(j)}(1)=j!\left(\frac{1-p}{p}\right)^j$.